# Maven Eclipse Plugin classpathContainer with attributes?

Tags: attributes, optional-parameters, maven-eclipse-plugin

I can set the classpathContainer parameter in my pom for a configuration of the Maven Eclipse Plugin for the command eclipse:eclipse. If I set:

```
<classpathContainers>
    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_29</classpathContainer>
</classpathContainers>
```

I get in my **.class**

```
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_29"/>
```

But I need:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.6.0_29">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

How can I add attributes to the classpathContainer?

Thanks in advance.